# Why does this Switch statement require parenthesis for 'Switch Value' and 'Compound case'?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, structure

I'm pretty new to Swift so still tinkering and finding my way around. I just wondering why I have to wrap the Switch value `chicken.breed, chicken.temper` and compound case `Breed.leghorn, Temper.hilarious` around parenthesises. **See error below when I remove the parenthesis**

**Context** 
The goal of the exercise is to increment `chickenOfInterestCount` whenever interesting chickens were found matching the `Breed` and `Temper` values I wanted to check. So I used a Switch statement to perform these

**Exercise.swift**

```
var chickenOfInterestCount = 0

for chicken in chickens {

    // check the chicken variables breed and temper enums
    switch (chicken.breed, chicken.temper){
        case (Breed.leghorn, Temper.hilarious):
            chickenOfInterestCount += 1
        default:
            print("No match")
    }
}

print(chickenOfInterestCount)
```

**Chicken.swift**

```
public enum Breed {
    case leghorn, rhodeIsland, silkie, plymouthRock
}

public enum Temper {
    case friendly, grumpy, hilarious
}

public struct Chicken {
    public let breed: Breed
    public let temper: Temper
}


public let chickens: [Chicken] = [
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .grumpy),
    Chicken(breed: .rhodeIsland, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .hilarious),
    Chicken(breed: .rhodeIsland, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .rhodeIsland, temper: .grumpy),
    Chicken(breed: .silkie, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .rhodeIsland, temper: .grumpy),
    Chicken(breed: .silkie, temper: .grumpy),
    Chicken(breed: .rhodeIsland, temper: .hilarious),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .silkie, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .hilarious),
    Chicken(breed: .plymouthRock, temper: .grumpy),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .grumpy),
    Chicken(breed: .silkie, temper: .grumpy),
    Chicken(breed: .plymouthRock, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .friendly),
    Chicken(breed: .leghorn, temper: .friendly),
]
```

Error when removing parenthensis

```
error: 19_EnumsAndSwitch.playground:9:25: error: expected '{' after 'switch' subject expression
    switch chicken.breed, chicken.temper{
                        ^

error: 19_EnumsAndSwitch.playground:10:9: error: 'case' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement
        case (Breed.leghorn, Temper.hilarious):
        ^

error: 19_EnumsAndSwitch.playground:12:9: error: 'default' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement
        default:
        ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `switch` takes one expression. By putting the two values in parentheses you are creating a tuple and the case statements match on the tuples.

Without the parentheses you are trying to put two comma separated expressions where there can only be one.

When you use a `switch` on a tuple, the cases allow you to match various combinations of tuples against the one in the `switch` expression.

For more on this, see the [Tuples and Switch](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID132) section in the Swift book.

Comment: Cheers. Essentially I could store my initial switch value to test in a constant? I wasn't aware of `Tuple` so early in my learning!